# How to import java project as module in java web project using intelijj?

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I wanted to use the class from basic java project inside java servlet class which is defined in another project.
I tried importing project as module through the module dependency InteliJ menu.
At compile time ,it is not giving any error ,but after running the server(Glassfish) and calling the servlet it is giving below error.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/practise/LogFileCreator at UserLoginValidator.dbConnectionMaker(UserLoginValidator.java:31)>

Please find below code which causing error.

**below class is from web project**

```
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;

import com.practise.LogFileCreator;

public class UserLoginValidator extends HttpServlet
{
    public String LogFilePath="D:\\Logs";
    public PrintWriter out;
    String errormsg="";
   //********************
    LogFileCreator l ;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

            try {
                this.l = new LogFileCreator(LogFilePath); // here i am trying to create object of my class which causing the mentioned error.
                l.WriteLog("Hello");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        

    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

    }


}
```

**below class is from normal java project**

```
package com.practise;
import java.io.*;

public class LogFileCreator
{
    private String filepath;
    private StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Log");
    private File file;
    private FileWriter fileWriter;
    private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    public PrintWriter p;

    public LogFileCreator(String filepath) throws IOException
    {
        this.filepath=filepath;
        String filename=sb.toString().concat(java.time.LocalDate.now().toString());
        this.file = new File(this.filepath,filename);
        this.fileWriter= new FileWriter(file,true);
        if(!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        p= new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

    }

    public void WriteLog(String logMessage){
        p.println(java.time.LocalDateTime.now() + " : " + logMessage);
        p.flush();
    }
}
```

Here is the image for module dependency I used .
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7KXW.png)

*Earlier I was using LogFileCreator.java class from same web project and it was working fine*

> Here what i am trying to acheive is ,without writing the LogFileCreator class again in web project ,wants to reuse the class written already inside normal java project to print the logs in desired text file .

Any solution/suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you!

**[Edit 1]**
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.jre11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>Logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
<!--    String Driver= "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";-->
<!--    String dbusername="sa";-->
<!--    String dbpassword="Admin@123";-->
<!--    String connectionString="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=Users;";-->
<!--    -->


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably how the deployment file (assuming war) was packaged. How are you building the file? Maven, Gradle, neither, etc.?

**Edit**

I wanted to give a bit more clarity for others who might stumble upon a similar issue. During compile time, the project/module in question was imported; however, maven does not know to package that library in the generated war. When it was deployed to Glassfish, the war did not contain the LogFileCreator class because it was not packaged in the war. The authors solution worked because maven is packaging the module into the war and Glassfish can now find the class.

Comment: Thanks for reply .
I have attached pom.xml in post .
Kindly check and suggest if anything am doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

**Here What I did which resolved the above problem.**

First I converted my first basic java project to maven project .
secondly I added maven dependency for the 2nd project (web project) and also added the jar file (of first project classes ) inside the web INF/lib directory of web project using below option from InteliJ .
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omp6p.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The server's classloader does not have a copy of LogFileCreator.class so the class is not on it's classpath.